# Can one replace a file deployed using InstallShield 2012 without having to package and redeploy the whole application

Tags: .net, deployment, installshield

We have an application that is developed and rolled to about 120 users whenever there is an upgrade, using InstallShield 2012. Sometimes a change might be on a single (.rdlc) report object eg. modifying parameters. In such a case is there a way of changing just the .rdlc file and copying it to the report folder on the User's PC. Are there any other files that I need to replace besides the one that I have made changes to.

Answer (score 0):

[A patch](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield12helplib/IHelpPatchStrategy.htm) is what you need, assuming you have a Windows Installer compliant package created with IS. You can find more details in the first link, or in [this video](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=2h8RQxzTyLY&desktop_uri=/watch?v=2h8RQxzTyLY).